# WebKit framework - how to handle request event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, webview, webkit

After loading website my application inject some javascirpt code (using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`).
How to inject some code when user goes on the subpage by clicking some link on this page?
I use WebView class ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webview#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WebView)).

Answer (score 0):

You should set your object as WebView's `frameLoadDelegate`, and override `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` method. In this method implementation, you should inject script, f.e. via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method.